# Android update only part of TextView's text

Tags: android

I have textview and text in it. my text looks like this: 1123974.13

every 0.1 second I need to make my text larger for 0.01. Since my Textview gets updated every 0.1 second it makes my text look weird like its vibrating since all the digits are updated so often.

I would like to know is there any elegant way (Not with using 2 or more textviews!) to make my textview update for example only last 2 digits.
In that case part of number: (1123974.1)... would not be changed all the time and only one digit would update.
This way it would have much better user experience

Comment: `ellipsize` does not work?

Comment: What do you mean to do with ellipsize, did you understand the question. I don't want to have 3 dots anywhere, I want that only last 2 digits update..?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. I would add some if condition that updates the textview just every 10th time. Once a second is probably often enough for the user but not too often for the phone.

Comment: I don't think that the flickering is only due to updating very often. I think you have your text centered or something which makes the rest of the text move a bit even if it is not changed. Try making your text aligned to the left so that even when you change the right most part the left part doesn't move

Comment: Plus why would you update so often. Updating 10 times a second is so quick the user would start having headaches just by looking at it. lol

Comment: If its font is not a monospace one, the number it displays will seem "vibrating" due to different text alignment of the changing value.